# Не могу передать данные из одного класса в другой (Python 3, PyQt5)

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты

Я так и не смог понять, как передать данные из одного класса в другой.
Есть два дисплея, на одном вводят информацию, на другой она передается.
Для каждого дисплея есть по **`2`** класса. Классы в префиксом `"UI"` созданы с помощью *PyQt5*. Два других созданы для произведения расчетов.

Я пишу `self` далее название того `класса`, передаю данные и название `элемента`, в который инфа отправляется, но у меня не выходит

В строке кода **`209`** пытаюсь отправить данные для секундомера(минуты/секунды) на первый дисплей - Выдает ошибку.
В строке **`242`** пытаюсь отправить данные по нажатию кнопки на первый дисплей - так же безуспешно.
На дисплее, где ввожу данные, их получается обработать, и показать на этом же дисплее, а передать на другой не получается.

````
import sys
from tkinter.tix import Form
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QSizePolicy, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout


class KumiteSWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi2(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(920, 680)

        self.time_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 0, 191, 141))
        self.time_21.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_21.setObjectName("time_1")

        self.time_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 0, 221, 141))
        self.time_22.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_22.setObjectName("time_2")

        self.time_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 0, 21, 141))
        self.time_23.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_23.setObjectName("time_3")

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 750, 640, 71))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.label_score21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_score21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(265, 100, 350, 450))
        self.label_score21.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_score21.setObjectName("label_score1")

        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 890, 640, 71))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")

        self.time_21.raise_()
        self.time_22.raise_()
        self.time_23.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.label_score21.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Display"))
        self.time_21.setText(_translate("Form", "00"))
        self.time_22.setText(_translate("Form", "00"))
        self.time_23.setText(_translate("Form", ":"))
        self.label_score21.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))


class KumiteSecondWindow(QWidget, KumiteSWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi2(self)


class KumiteMainWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form2):
        Form2.setObjectName("Form")
        Form2.resize(900, 500)
        Form2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.time_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
        self.time_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(362, 0, 80, 60))
        self.time_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_11.setObjectName("time_1")

        self.time_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
        self.time_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(458, 0, 80, 60))
        self.time_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_12.setObjectName("time_2")

        self.time_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
        self.time_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 0, 21, 60))
        self.time_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_13.setObjectName("time_3")

        self.time_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
        self.time_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(535, 35, 31, 21))
        self.time_14.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_14.setObjectName("time_4")

        self.frame_red1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form2)
        self.frame_red1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 60, 400, 240))
        self.frame_red1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 222, 219);")
        self.frame_red1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_red1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_red1.setObjectName("frame_red")

        self.label_score11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_red1)
        self.label_score11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 20, 100, 200))
        self.label_score11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_score11.setObjectName("label_score1")

        self.score_red_0 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 8, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_0.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_0.setChecked(True)
        self.score_red_0.setObjectName("score_red_0")

        self.score_red_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 41, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_1.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_1.setObjectName("score_red_1")

        self.score_red_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 74, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_2.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_2.setObjectName("score_red_2")

        self.pushButton_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_reset.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 15, 81, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_reset.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_reset.setObjectName("pushButton_reset")

        self.pushButton_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_pause.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 20, 111, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_pause.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_pause.setObjectName("pushButton_pause")

        self.pushButton_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_start.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_start.setObjectName("pushButton_start")


        self.frame_red1.raise_()
        self.time_11.raise_()
        self.time_12.raise_()
        self.time_13.raise_()
        self.pushButton_reset.raise_()
        self.pushButton_pause.raise_()
        self.pushButton_start.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form2", "DisplayDataInput"))
        self.time_11.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.time_12.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.time_13.setText(_translate("Form2", ":"))
        self.time_14.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.label_score11.setText(_translate("Form2", "0"))
        self.score_red_1.setText(_translate("Form2", " 1"))
        self.score_red_2.setText(_translate("Form2", "2"))
        self.pushButton_reset.setText(_translate("Form2", "Новый бой\n(обнулить всё)"))
        self.pushButton_pause.setText(_translate("Form2", "Обнулить таймер"))
        self.pushButton_start.setText(_translate("Form2", "Start"))


class KumiteMainWindow(QWidget, KumiteMainWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.KumiteSecondWindow = KumiteSecondWindow

        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.pushButton_pause.clicked.connect(self.reset_timer)
        self.pushButton_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset_all)
        self.score_red_0.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)
        self.score_red_1.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)
        self.score_red_2.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)

        self.tics = 0
        self.increment = 100
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)

    def update_time(self):
        self.tics += self.increment
        m = (self.tics // 60000) % 60
        s = (self.tics // 1000) % 60
        ms = (self.tics // 10) % 100
        self.time_11.setText(f'{m:02d}')
        self.time_12.setText(f'{s:02d}')
        self.time_14.setText(f'{ms:01d}')
#        self.KumiteSecondWindow.time_21.setText(f'{m:02d}')

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Start':
            self.pushButton_start.setText('Stop')
            self.timer.start(self.increment)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton_start.setText('Start')

    def reset_timer(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Stop':
            self.pushButton_pause.setText('Останови бой')
        else:
            self.tics = 0
            self.time_11.setText('00')
            self.time_12.setText('00')
            self.time_14.setText('00')
            self.pushButton_pause.setText('Обнулить таймер')

    def reset_all(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Stop':
            self.pushButton_reset.setText('Останови бой')
        else:
            self.tics = 0
            self.time_11.setText('00')
            self.time_12.setText('00')
            self.time_14.setText('00')

    def onClickedR(self):
        radio = self.sender()
        if radio.isChecked():
            self.label_score11.setText(radio.text())
#            self.KumiteSecondWindow.label_score21.setText(radio.text())

    def onClickedW(self):
        radio = self.sender()
        if radio.isChecked():
            self.label_score12.setText(radio.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = KumiteSecondWindow()
    Form2 = KumiteMainWindow()
    Form.show()
    Form2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())```
````

Comment: Часть информации куда-то пропала! вначале поста здоровался :) и просил помощи

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы почти были у цели. Я отметил для вас строки, в которые внес изменения. Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

```
import sys
# ? from tkinter.tix import Form
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QBrush
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QTimer
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QLabel, QPushButton, QGridLayout, \
    QSizePolicy, QApplication, QMainWindow, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout


class KumiteSWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi2(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(920, 680)

        self.time_21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(250, 0, 191, 141))
        self.time_21.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_21.setObjectName("time_1")

        self.time_22 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_22.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(480, 0, 221, 141))
        self.time_22.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_22.setObjectName("time_2")

        self.time_23 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.time_23.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 0, 21, 141))
        self.time_23.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_23.setObjectName("time_3")

        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 750, 640, 71))
        self.frame.setStyleSheet("background-color: white; border-color: rgb(0, 0, 0)")
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")

        self.label_score21 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form)
        self.label_score21.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(265, 100, 350, 450))
        self.label_score21.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_score21.setObjectName("label_score1")

        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(120, 890, 640, 71))
        self.frame_2.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.NoFrame)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")

        self.time_21.raise_()
        self.time_22.raise_()
        self.time_23.raise_()
        self.frame_2.raise_()
        self.label_score21.raise_()
        self.frame.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Display"))
        self.time_21.setText(_translate("Form", "00"))
        self.time_22.setText(_translate("Form", "00"))
        self.time_23.setText(_translate("Form", ":"))
        self.label_score21.setText(_translate("Form", "0"))


class KumiteMainWindow_Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form2):
        Form2.setObjectName("Form")
        Form2.resize(900, 500)
        Form2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);")

        self.time_11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
#        self.time_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(362, 0, 80, 60))
        self.time_11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 0, 40, 60))                       # +
        self.time_11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignRight | 
                                  QtCore.Qt.AlignTrailing | 
                                  QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_11.setObjectName("time_1")

        self.time_12 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
#        self.time_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(458, 0, 80, 60))
        self.time_12.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(400, 0, 40, 60))                       # +
        
        self.time_12.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading | 
                                  QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | 
                                  QtCore.Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.time_12.setObjectName("time_2")

        self.time_13 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
#        self.time_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 0, 21, 60))
        self.time_13.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 0, 10, 60))                       # +

        self.time_13.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_13.setObjectName("time_3")

        self.time_14 = QtWidgets.QLabel(Form2)
#        self.time_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(450, 0, 40, 21))
        self.time_14.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(460, 0, 40, 60))                       # +
        
        self.time_14.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.time_14.setObjectName("time_4")

        self.frame_red1 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form2)
        self.frame_red1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(25, 60, 400, 240))
        self.frame_red1.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 222, 219);")
        self.frame_red1.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_red1.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_red1.setObjectName("frame_red")

        self.label_score11 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.frame_red1)
        self.label_score11.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 20, 100, 200))
        self.label_score11.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.label_score11.setObjectName("label_score1")

        self.score_red_0 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_0.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 8, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_0.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_0.setChecked(True)
        self.score_red_0.setObjectName("score_red_0")

        self.score_red_1 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 41, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_1.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_1.setObjectName("score_red_1")

        self.score_red_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.frame_red1)
        self.score_red_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 74, 40, 25))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        font.setPointSize(15)
        self.score_red_2.setFont(font)
        self.score_red_2.setObjectName("score_red_2")

        self.pushButton_reset = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_reset.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(570, 15, 81, 30))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_reset.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_reset.setObjectName("pushButton_reset")

        self.pushButton_pause = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_pause.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 20, 111, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_pause.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_pause.setObjectName("pushButton_pause")

        self.pushButton_start = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form2)
        self.pushButton_start.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 20, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Gotham")
        self.pushButton_start.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton_start.setObjectName("pushButton_start")


        self.frame_red1.raise_()
        self.time_11.raise_()
        self.time_12.raise_()
        self.time_13.raise_()
        self.pushButton_reset.raise_()
        self.pushButton_pause.raise_()
        self.pushButton_start.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(Form2)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form2)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form2):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form2.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form2", "DisplayDataInput"))
        self.time_11.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.time_12.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.time_13.setText(_translate("Form2", ":"))
        self.time_14.setText(_translate("Form2", "00"))
        self.label_score11.setText(_translate("Form2", "0"))
        self.score_red_1.setText(_translate("Form2", " 1"))
        self.score_red_2.setText(_translate("Form2", "2"))
        self.pushButton_reset.setText(_translate("Form2", "Новый бой\n(обнулить всё)"))
        self.pushButton_pause.setText(_translate("Form2", "Обнулить таймер"))
        self.pushButton_start.setText(_translate("Form2", "Start"))


class KumiteSecondWindow(QWidget, KumiteSWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi2(self)


class KumiteMainWindow(QWidget, KumiteMainWindow_Ui):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

#        self.KumiteSecondWindow = KumiteSecondWindow
#             ^
# не надо экземпляр класса называть с заглавной буквы
#            v
#            v                                  скобки !!!
#            v                                      vv                      # <<< !!!
        self.kumiteSecondWindow = KumiteSecondWindow()                      # kumiteSecondWindow
        self.kumiteSecondWindow.show()                                      # +++

        self.pushButton_start.clicked.connect(self.start_timer)
        self.pushButton_pause.clicked.connect(self.reset_timer)
        self.pushButton_reset.clicked.connect(self.reset_all)
        self.score_red_0.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)
        self.score_red_1.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)
        self.score_red_2.toggled.connect(self.onClickedR)

        self.tics = 0
        self.increment = 100
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_time)

    def update_time(self):
        self.tics += self.increment
        m = (self.tics // 60000) % 60
        s = (self.tics // 1000) % 60
        ms = (self.tics // 10) % 100
        self.time_11.setText(f'm : {m:02d}')
        self.time_12.setText(f's : {s:02d}')
        self.time_14.setText(f'ms: {ms:01d}')
        
#        self.KumiteSecondWindow.time_21.setText(f'{m:02d}')
        self.kumiteSecondWindow.time_21.setText(f'{m:02d}')
        self.kumiteSecondWindow.time_22.setText(f'{s:02d}')                            # +++

    def start_timer(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Start':
            self.pushButton_start.setText('Stop')
            self.timer.start(self.increment)
        else:
            self.timer.stop()
            self.pushButton_start.setText('Start')

    def reset_timer(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Stop':
            self.pushButton_pause.setText('Останови бой')
        else:
            self.tics = 0
            self.time_11.setText('00')
            self.time_12.setText('00')
            self.time_14.setText('00')
            self.pushButton_pause.setText('Обнулить таймер')

    def reset_all(self):
        if self.pushButton_start.text() == 'Stop':
            self.pushButton_reset.setText('Останови бой')
        else:
            self.tics = 0
            self.time_11.setText('00')
            self.time_12.setText('00')
            self.time_14.setText('00')

    def onClickedR(self):
        radio = self.sender()
        if radio.isChecked():
            self.label_score11.setText(radio.text())
            self.kumiteSecondWindow.label_score21.setText(radio.text())            # !!!

    def onClickedW(self):
        radio = self.sender()
        if radio.isChecked():
            self.label_score12.setText(radio.text())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#    Form = KumiteSecondWindow()                                                   # НЕТ  !!!
    Form2 = KumiteMainWindow()
#    Form.show()                                                                   # НЕТ  !!!
    Form2.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ,а почему `Form = KumiteSecondWindow()` и `Form.show()` было ошибкой?

Comment: Ник, ещё раз огромное спасибо! Со скобками когда определял экземпляр класс - это вообще провал (((( Буду учиться, нужно изучать азы! Огромное спасибо!

Comment: @dutik это как бы не ошибка, а пустой выхлоп, а отсутствие скобок - считаем опечаткой и после создания экземпляра второго окна, не забывайте  показать его (`show`).